# LibGDX Android: Lag with 25+ sprites despite use of TimeKeeping

Tags: java, android, libgdx

**The Problem** I have ArrayList of "pellets". I'm pushing around 25 of them and they all bounce. However, for some reason they seem to go faster while render() is slower / takes more time (wut?) *Please help me make it so that the 25 sprites smoothly glide about at a constant speed. It also jerks when only 5 sprites are onScreen.*

Tried this stuff:

- Reading around SO. They recommended getDeltaTime
- Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() multiplying by pelletSpeed (no Change)
- In the current code the pellets hop, jerk, and inconsistently sputter about almost unpredictably. I am assuming that it's going constant speed underneath the hood but honestly it's hard to tell

For Loop in Render:

```
String currentDir = pelletList.get(i).getDir();
String currentColor = pelletList.get(i).getColor6();
pelletSpeedElapsedTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
if(currentDir.equals("Up")) {
    pelletList.get(i).y -= pelletSpeed * TimeUtils.timeSinceNanos(pelletSpeedElapsedTime);
    if(pelletList.get(i).y < 0 ) {
        pelletList.get(i).setDir("Down");
    }
} else if (currentDir.equals("Down")) {
    pelletList.get(i).y += pelletSpeed * TimeUtils.timeSinceNanos(pelletSpeedElapsedTime);
    if(pelletList.get(i).y > screenHeight) {
        pelletList.get(i).setDir("Up");
    }
} else if (currentDir.equals("Left")) {
    pelletList.get(i).x -= pelletSpeed * TimeUtils.timeSinceNanos(pelletSpeedElapsedTime);
    if(pelletList.get(i).x < 0) {
        pelletList.get(i).setDir("Right");
    }
} else if (currentDir.equals("Right")) {
    pelletList.get(i).x += pelletSpeed * TimeUtils.timeSinceNanos(pelletSpeedElapsedTime);
    if(pelletList.get(i).x > screenWidth) {
        pelletList.get(i).setDir("Left");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `pelletSpeedElapsedTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();` looks suspicious to me - you're getting this time, and then calculating elapsed time for bullets immediately afterward. Almost no time will have elapsed by then, and you won't be accounting at all for whatever time passes before the next call to whatever method this is.

I think (guessing at what the rest of your code is like) that you want to move that `pelletSpeedElapsedTime` assignment to the end of this method. The idea here is that you want to capture the time where you *finished* this update, so that the next time you update you know how much time has passed between updates (e.g. time spent rendering, sleeping, whatever.)

Doing this would mean that you'd have to handle the case where `pelletSpeedElapsedTime` hasn't been initialized, as well (maybe initialize it in the constructor? again, not sure of the broader context.)  Also, I don't think all those `TimeUtils.timeSinceNanos` calls or necessary - I would call that once at the start of this section of code and use the value (to make sure the moving entities all get a consistent time delta, and to avoid the redundant call/calculation.)

Comment: Hang on a second if all the TimeUtils.timeSinceNanos is in an if-else, then its only called once? Does it make a difference to eval at the beginning? Thanks

Comment: OK After moving the location of pelletElapsedTime, the pellets all vary in speed, some super fast some slow, some medium